# File Transfer function freezes after first success

Tags: java, file-transfer

I have attempted to write a program that simply sends files from the client to server. The program has a gui where you enter the file path and what you want the new filename to be on the server. The program works fine for the first send but freezes on the second send and the second file does not get written to server. Any help would be appreciated im really stuck thank you guys so much in advance.

**Client Code**

```
ServerSocket serverSocket;
    public void sendFile(String filePath, String fileFieldName)throws IOException{

        //Parameters filePath is a full direct path of file to be sent
        //Example of filePath "C:\Users\Someone\Desktop\Capture3333333.PNG"
        //FileFieldName is the desired name and extension of file being sent

        // i removed my server ip and just put in a string for demonstration
    Socket socket = new Socket("IP GOES HERE", 5557); 
    System.out.println("Is sending?");
    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(bos);
    File files = new File(filePath);
    long length = files.length();
    dos.writeLong(length);

    dos.writeUTF("\\"+ fileFieldName);

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filePath);
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);

    int theByte = 0;
    while((theByte = bis.read()) != -1) bos.write(theByte);

    bis.close();
    bos.flush();

    dos.close();
    }
```

**Server Code**

```
     ServerSocket serverSocket;

    public void fileListenThread () throws IOException {

        while(true){//This is so the socket keeps listening
         serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5557);
    Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();

    if(socket.isConnected()){
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);
    File files ;

    long fileLength = dis.readLong();//This reads file length from client
    String fileName = dis.readUTF();//This reads filename from client
    files = new File( System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\Desktop\\Top-Brand\\Images\\" + fileName );//File received from client is written to this path
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(files);
    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

    for(int j = 0; j < fileLength; j++)
        bos.write(bis.read());
    bos.flush();
    bos.close();
    dis.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you debug the client and server? where does it get stuck?

Comment: Hello, I am a novice and i have not yet figured out how to use the netbeans debugger. I am going to watch a how to on youtube. However i did run the program a few more times and caught an error i was able to replicate 3 times successively. The error is in the server :

Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind

at topbrandserver.TopBrandServer.fileListenThread(TopBrandServer.java:201)

Answer (score 1):

Move the line

```
serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5557);
```

out of the while loop. It should be before the loop, not inside it. If you put it in the loop, then after each file transfer, you will be creating another server socket which will then fail to bind because the old one is still there.

Comment: WORKS LIKE A CHARM THANK YOU SO MUCH. I WAS SO TUNNELED ON OTHER THINGS I DIDNT SEE THE ERROR RIGHT IN FRONT OF ME. YOU ARE A GENIUS AND GOD AMONG MEN.

Comment: @PieGuy Good to hear. I'm a bit puzzled though as to why you posted the same thing as a separate answer rather than just accepting this one.

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED - My server socket was inside the loop causing a net bind exception, here is working code  for server, client works just fine

```
     ServerSocket serverSocket;

    public void fileListenThread () throws IOException {
      serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5557);
        while(true){//This is so the socket keeps listening

    Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();

    if(socket.isConnected()){
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);
    File files ;

    long fileLength = dis.readLong();//This reads file length from client
    String fileName = dis.readUTF();//This reads filename from client
    files = new File( System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\Desktop\\Top-Brand\\Images\\" + fileName );//File received from client is written to this path
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(files);
    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

    for(int j = 0; j < fileLength; j++)
        bos.write(bis.read());
    bos.flush();
    bos.close();
    dis.close();
        }
    }
}
```